# Unable to start the nvidia GPu drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, ubuntu-studio

I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, and I am trying to get higher performances for a video game (FlightGear). According to `lspci`, I got two GPU's on my Acer TravelMate 5360:

```sh
~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)
```

But the `nvidia` drivers seem not to work:

```sh
~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:10198): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:41:24.368: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 15:41:24.374: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 15:41:24.374: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

I tried to manually activate the nvidia drivers:

```sh
~$ sudo modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': No such device
~$ sudo modprobe nvidia_drm
~$ dmesg
[...]
[  266.952607] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 235
[  266.955482] NVRM: The NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M GPU installed in this system is
               NVRM:  supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please
               NVRM:  visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more
               NVRM:  information.  The 470.57.02 NVIDIA driver will ignore
               NVRM:  this GPU.  Continuing probe...
[  266.955489] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[  266.955719] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 235
```

According to the website specified in the `dmesg` message, my GPU is supported only until version 390. But installing that version makes my screen stay black when the login screen should appear upon boot. Right now, I have the newest version (470) installed. What can I do ?

EDIT: I tried all the solutions in the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers), but *none of them* helped. I also just tried reinstalling the 390 nvidia drivers - I again got a black login screen. Interestingly, when I add `nomodeset` to the kernel boot parameters in Grub, I get the login screen, and the desktop after that, too. `nvidia-smi` then shows the expected output:

```sh
~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jul 26 20:04:29 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.144                Driver Version: 390.144                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 520M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   56C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /   964MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But nvidia-settings still shows this:

```sh
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:10198): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:41:24.368: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 15:41:24.374: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 15:41:24.374: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 15:41:24.467: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

and has only one page `PRIME profile` available. Also I can by no means adjust my screen brightness (`xrandr`, `xbacklight` `backlightctl`) - all just do nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/a/680831/66509)

Comment: @N0rbert no it doesn't - edited.